# How to shorten php code, in multiple combination of form result

Tags: php

I have a php page that contains a form with 7 drop down boxes.
The problem is that the 0 to 6 boxes may be unselected.

It would be a lot of work to make a `switch` with a `case` for every combination.

What other method can i use?

thanks,
Sebastian

**EDIT**

For each combination i have to make different queries that contain only the selected items from the drop-boxes.

Ex. If the user selects 3 from the 7, the query has to pass 3 conditions.

**EDIT2**
I don't know what the values of the drop-boxes are. Because they are built up using an mysql query in a `while` statement

**SOLUTION**

I've found a solution that should work. I haven't tested it yet.
First of all i want to check if what is selected in the drop-boxes.
`If($_POST[telefon]="empty"){$tel=""}

else{$tel="WHERE telefon =' "}`

after this i can concatenate the `$tel` string with the `$_POST['telefon']` string.
`$query_tel=$tel.$_POST['telefon']." ' ";`

Final query string would look like this `$query="SELECT * table ".$query_telefon." ,".$query_ziua....(and so on)`

Of course i have to be very careful with the query that will result, for missing commas, apostrophes and so on. But i guess it's the simplest way.

Comment: It really depends on what you are planning to do with the data. Maybe add more detail

Comment: That's a very unspecific question. Please, post some code example of what you want to illustrate it

Comment: @Russel Dias, that would be about the same with `SWITCH`

Comment: probably i have not understoud well, but try to use array with ternary operator

Comment: sebastian I hope I understood you well I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**ASSUMPTION:** the point here is you want reduce code in relation with number of query!

**PREMISE:** the use of `switch` or `and/if` are both valid approach anyway!

> - for reducing your code to one line for all the queries, your SQL column name and SELECT html element should be called the same, like:

```
t_apple VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
t_peach VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
t_strawberry VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
... 

<select name="t_apple"></select>
<select name="t_peach"></select>
<select name="t_strawberry"></select>
...
```

try this:

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $form_button = array_pop($_POST); //remove the submit button val
    $new_array = array_filter( $_POST , 'strlen'); //remove empty value from $_POST
    foreach( $new_array as $key => $val ) {

     //optionaly make some other check here if ($val != '---')

    // "INSERT INTO {$key} VALUES ( {$val} )"
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to preset the values and then overwriting them:

```
$array(
    'dropdown1' => 'value1',
    'dropdown2' => 'value2',
    'dropdown3' => 'value3',
    'dropdown4' => 'value4',
    'dropdown5' => 'value5',
    'dropdown6' => 'value6'
)

$array = $_POST;
```

This way you can set the default values and just overwrite the array with the post array send from the form.

**EDIT:**
if you set the empty value to 'empty' like this:

```
<select name="dropdown[dropdownnamehere]">
    <option value='empty'>---</option>
</select>
```

You will be able to loop trough the values and only select the set ones

```
foreach($_POST['dropdown'] as $item => $value)
{
    if($value != 'empty')
    {
        //create a mysql part here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But i can't do this because i don't know what the values will be, because the values are written in a `while` statement. like this: `    <option value='---'>---</option>";
   while($trunchiRow = mysql_fetch_array($trunchiResult)) {
    $trunchi1 = $trunchiRow['linie'];
    echo "<option value='$trunchi1'>$trunchi1</option>";
   }   
   echo"</select></td></tr>"; `

Comment: i don't know if this would help. because any of my 7 drop-boxes can be empty. Also there can be 0 to 6 empty.

Comment: this loop only loops trough the entered boxes so it doesn't matter what box is empty. the only part you need to do now it to generate a query from the loop.